# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

i have this reaction role system everything works up to the last part where the coulour slection happens

```
      async run(message, client, con) {
    await message.channel.send("Give the color for the embed.")
        answer = await message.channel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id === message.author.id,{max: 1});
        var color = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join()).toUpperCase()
        if(color.toUpperCase()==='CANCEL') return (message.channel.send("The Process Has Been Cancelled!"))
    function embstr(){
        var finalString = '';
        for(var i =0;i<n;i++){
            
            finalString += b[i]+ ' - '+a[i] +'\n';
        }
        return finalString;
    }
    const botmsg = message.client.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.id === reactChannel)
    
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(embtitle)
        .setColor(color)
        .setDescription(embstr());
        
        botmsg.send(embed);
        message.channel.send("Reaction Role has been created successfully")
```

here is the error message

```
{
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at SlowmodeCommand.run (B:\\stuff\\Downloads\\Admeeeeeen bot\\src\\commands\\reactionroles\\createreactionrole.js:100:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get()` method takes in a snowflake as its parameter. AKA an ID of a certain object. It is not an iterator, meaning that what you're currently attempting to do is not right JavaScript wise.

Instead of passing in a parameter to represent a channel object, we'll just want to pass in the ID of the channel that we'd like to get. Alternatively, you could replace `.get()` with `.find()` there, which is in fact an iterator that uses this form of a callback, although it's insufficient in our case considering we can just use `.get()` which is more accurate when it comes to IDs.

```js
    /**
    * Insufficient code:
    * const botmsg = message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === reactChannel)
    */
    const botmsg = message.client.channels.cache.get(reactChannel /* assuming that reactChannel represents a channel ID */)
```